# POS Thermal printer vendor file

Tags: github, thermal-printer, vendor

I've Downloaded the code from github `https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php`

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
    use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
    $connector = new FilePrintConnector("/dev/usb/lp0");
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    
    $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
    $printer -> cut();
    
    $printer -> close();
```

In this code vendor directory is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a PHP Composer feature.

[COMPOSER](https://getcomposer.org/)

> A Dependency Manager for PHP

[Autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and start using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work:

Please refer to the explanation linked above.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth adding that the 'vendor' folder (along with composer.json and composer.lock) need to be in the **project directory**